# Heroku Toolbelt not found

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku-toolbelt

I'm on a Mac, Maverick.

Since a few weeks (I think it started with the Maverick install but I'm not sure), the Toolbelt doesn't work anymore as it should.

When I run an heroku command, I get this error message:

```
/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p0/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/dependency.rb:296:in `to_specs': Could not find 'heroku' (>= 0) among 490 total gem(s) (Gem::LoadError)
    from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p0/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/dependency.rb:307:in `to_spec'
    from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p0/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_gem.rb:47:in `gem'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0@global/bin/heroku:22:in `<main>'
```

When I reinstall heroku toolbelt with the client, after restarting the terminal, it works but only in the root directory and not for long...

when I do

```
heroku version, I get: heroku-toolbelt/3.0.1 (x86_64-darwin10.8.0) ruby/1.9.3
```

When I do

```
which heroku, I get: heroku: aliased to nocorrect heroku
```

My paths are OK.

What can I do?

Thanks!

Comment: does reinstalling the heroku toolbelt work?

Comment: only for some time (then it stops working and I don't know why) and only in the root directory

Comment: Well, don't install the `heroku toolbelt`. Install the `heroku` and `foreman` gem from the terminal instead.